# Obtain user information from bearer_token O365 for currently logged in user

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, bearer-token, o365-flow

I have a bearer token from O365 and when i decode it no user information of the currently logged in user is present. I am able to obtain a token and decoded using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). The user information i require is the family_name, given_name and name of the user.

I can obtain a token with the user information however only if i change the grant_type to password and i specify a username and password. This gives me a delegated token with a refresh token and it contains the user information i require but this wont be possible based on the requirements.

Is there another way to obtain the user information from the token without changing the grant type to password?

**Token Request using Ajax Request**

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
form.append("client_id", "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx");
form.append("client_secret", "xxxxxxxxxx");
form.append("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {

    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "4b326d42-a15d-c1ef-e2d3-2fb7f690b2ac"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

**Bearer Token Result**

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImllX3FXQ1hoWHh0MXpJRXN1NGM3YWNRVkduNCIsImtpZCI6ImllX3FXQ1hoWHh0MXpJRXN1NGM3YWNRVkduNCJ9.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.nbRKMflEF7582CVhyyUDPV1KfwyjY1uMG9w5jRLGUkg_bkEiqqvjudT6X4s32szdSAYdwddXUmrWCoqPm5hkbPA4eOqDrYk_y-mvNZwrmr2ZdrpqH4ma_w39kuCIcq7_vRgKfpZ3r3i-c21Ilpgr92qI25WWqDOFgKVO1Pd4YVRqy9caZ7DVeiIp26BAqAFHwuLEEbhXakOqUXfh49LShzTwpzl-8UaIQBzyoiFUWksA2OdM1cTaf-LSTYjwKXu5IN7rJ7z6xkC3YSLmctOPP2a1Y3PpYAlGbKmSdde5do4rIckiFRcwoUsqGGFOkzuyHUwU0na26-DLDLEB8DJ1og
```

I am not to sure if the aud is correct

[image: Decoded JWT]

Comment: If you use Application Permission (appid & secret) there are nouser interaction and no user info.

Comment: Does this mean its not possible to get user information without using grant_type: password?. Is there any other way to obtain the logged in user?

Comment: In short No. There are no logger user, there are a logged application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and came across this solution which requires you to do these steps in an order to achieve the required information. Basically there is a code returned from the authorization (login) response that is used to obtain the token.

This token will contain the user information and is then used to access Microsoft Graph API and to get the user information. See  [Use the access token to call Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#4-use-the-access-token-to-call-microsoft-graph)